Retrieving Deleted Scheduled Posts via WordPress REST API
I've been using a Python script to fetch and modify posting day of scheduled posts in WordPress via the REST API with the following URL:https://{domain}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&post_status=future&post_type=post&orderby=date&order=asc  This script worked perfectly until a few days ago. Recently, it started retrieving posts that I had previously deleted, and these posts did not appear in the trash nor are they listed under the future or published post status in the WordPress admin. But After using this script, this ghost post appear from somewhere... Has anyone experienced a similar issue or solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
